# Multer Test Case UploadFile(req, res) Method using Jest

Tags: node.js, jestjs, multer

I need to write test cases for below method using Jest Framework.

How to write test cases for below method.

I have tried to write test case but getting error Cannot read property 'send' of undefined.

```
  async function uploadFile(req, res) {
  let storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, os.tmpdir());
    },
    filename(req, file, cb) {
      let fileExtension = path.extname(file.originalname);
      let filename = `${file.fieldname}-${uuidv4()}${fileExtension}`;
      req.body.filepath = `${os.tmpdir()}/${filename}`;
      cb(null, `${filename}`);
    },
  });

  let multerSingle = multer({
    storage: storage,
    fileFilter: (req, file, cb) => {
      const filetypes = [".xlsx", ".xls", ".xlsb"];
      const extname = path.extname(file.originalname).toLowerCase();
      if (filetypes.includes(extname)) cb(null, true);
      else cb(null, false);
    },
  }).single("pcr");

  multerSingle(req, res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      return res.send("Error uploading file.");
    }
  });
  return;
}
```

Comment: Unit test or integration test?